# Azure VMSS Flexible Orchestration - Custom Resource Names

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have created VMSS Flexible with orchestration mode with proper names, yet VMs, NICs, IPs got randomly generated suffixes.
[image]

Is it possible to automatically create VMs and corresponding resources, when adding instances through VMSS?
I’d like to have resources names like:

```
TST-WebServer1-VM
TST-WebServer2-VM
TST-WebServer1-VM-IP
TST-WebServer2-VM-IP
TST-WebServer1-VM-NIC
TST-WebServer2-VM-NIC
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-orchestration-modes#instance-naming

> When you create a VM and add it to a Flexible scale set, you have full control over instance names within the Azure Naming convention rules. When VMs are automatically added to the scale set via autoscaling, you provide a prefix and **Azure appends a unique number to the end of the name.**

Apparently it is not actually full control over the names when they are automatically added.